# unable to connect postgresql in android code on windows 7

Tags: android

i want to connect postgresql database in my android code...
for that first i install postgresql 9.1 and download the jdbc driver .....
and then follow the android code from below site

http://appliedcoffeetechnology.tumblr.com/post/10657124340

but i got the error message like

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

i checked all possible getconnection method but got same error...
so can u provide any advice
please.....

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the JDBC driver is not able to connect to the PostgreSQL
database.

Try out the following:

- See if there is any firewall running, run 'iptables -F" on the database
  server machine to disable it for a while and then test the same Java code
- Check the routing tables info and see if there is anything missing there.
- If the above two are okay and still its not connecting try out settng the
  following in your pg_hba.conf file:

host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32      trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0         trust

and then do a 'pg_ctl reload' and see if that now lets you connect through
the JDBC driver or not locally and over the lan.

Comment: or may be you can try your dynamic IP in pg_hba.conf file.It helps in some cases.

Comment: i want to get data from localhost in postgresql so is it compulsaury to take permission for android.permission.internet in androidManifest..xml?

Comment: As per my knowledge you cant access data from localhost becoz emulator itself run on localhost.you have to upload ur data either on IIS or server to call it in android.....